# Moving characters from one cell to another cause infinite loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a novice with Excel VBA and what I need to do is take a few cells in a column that contain a name and a phone number and cut the phone number out of that cell and paste it in another column, so I'll have one cell with the name and another with the number.

For some reason my program goes into an infinite loop.

I'm pretty sure it's caused by `sLen = sLen - 1`  & `j = j - 1` but I don't know how to solve it.

```
Sub loop_macro()

    Dim myStr As String
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 5 To 15
        myStr = movePhone(Cells(i, 2), i)

        Cells(i, 5) = myStr

    Next i

End Sub



Function movePhone(s As String, rowNum As Integer) As String

    Dim retval As String    // This is the return string to be copied to column 5
    Dim j As Integer        // Counter for character position.
    Dim sLen As Integer

    retval = ""    
    sLen = Len(s)

    For j = 1 To sLen
        If Mid(s, j, 1) >= "0" And Mid(s, j, 1) <= "9" Then
            retval = retval + Mid(s, j, 1)
            Cells(rowNum, 2) = Mid(Cells(rowNum, 2), j, 1) // remove digit from cell
            sLen = sLen - 1
            j = j - 1
        ElseIf Mid(s, j, 1) = "-" Then
            retval = retval + Mid(s, j, 1)
            Cells(rowNum, 2) = Mid(Cells(rowNum, 2), j, 1) // remove "-" char from cell
            sLen = sLen - 1
            j = j - 1

        End If
    Next

    movePhone = retval
End Function
```

Comment: just remove this rows: `sLen = sLen - 1` and `j = j - 1`. Code should work as expected. Btw, `Cells(rowNum, 2) = Mid(Cells(rowNum, 2), j, 1)` doesn't remove digit or `-`, but instead leaves only this character

Comment: I tried removing these rows but then the whole cell is being removed. But it could be because of the second thing you wrote. I'll try fixing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of messing around so much with manipulating J so you can go left to right go right to left like so:

```
for j = sLen to 1 step -1
```

Now you can ommit the line j=j-1 and it will no longer give you this problem.

Always start at the end and work your way to the start when removing things from strings or even data sets, it's much easier than manipulating the variable you are looping on.

In this instance you should consider using Regexp (Regular Expressions) I have not used them before but they will find number strings within strings (and so much more if you want). Search SO for regexp and you will find heaps of code to help you out.